# SP2016 CA Site Collection Error: User cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, 2016

I'm repairing a SP2016 site by restoring the MDF, attaching the DB, and CA > "Add Content DB".  In CA I'm able to "View Site Collections" and get details (the upper right display) when I click on the collections.  But a certain percentage of sites give me an error when I click on them to display the details: "Sorry, something went wrong.  User cannot be found."  It doesn't do it for all of the site collections; just about half of them.

This effect also happens at other places in CA, like when I try to run a backup on a Site Collection.

> Logs show:   Application error when access
>   /_admin/SiteCollections.aspx,    Error=User cannot be found.   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: User cannot be found.
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException 
>   (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: User cannot be
>   found. 
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)

If I can't have CA "ignore" the user, then is there a powershell script to set all users to the System Account?

Comment: check if you have any orphan or disabled users in the farm admin group? also who is site collection admin for the central admin site?

Comment: If I understand you correctly... I have two accounts in the Farm Administrators group.  I'm able to log into CA with both accounts.  And I get the same results with either account.  For site collection admins, initially they were all set to the same two logins.  When I "Change Site Collection" and choose an offending site collection, I get the same "User not found" error.

Comment: I was going to try to set the Site Collection owners via PS.  Per MSoft (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631156(v=office.16).aspx) this should work.  But the command "SecondaryOwnerAlias" is unrecognized in PowerShell, even though it's in their documentation (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607958(v=office.16).aspx).